# Not able find datastore.totalReadLatency.average using Get-StatType

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am trying to find Latency for a datastore.

below is the code

```
$vmName = ""

$stat = "datastore.totalReadLatency.average","datastore.totalWriteLatency.average"
$entity = Get-VM -Name $vmName | select -Unique
$start = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)

$dsTab = @{}
$dsTab = Get-Datastore | Where {$_.Type -eq "VMFS"} | %{
  $key = $_.ExtensionData.Info.Vmfs.Uuid
  if(!$dsTab.ContainsKey($key)){
    $dsTab.Add($key,$_.Name)
  }
  else{
    "Datastore $($_.Name) with UUID $key already in hash table"
  }
}

Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat -Start $start |
Group-Object -Property {$_.Entity.Name} | %{
  $vmName = $_.Values[0]
  $VMReadLatency = $_.Group |
    where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.totalReadLatency.average"} |
    Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
    Select -ExpandProperty Average
  $VMWriteLatency = $_.Group |
    where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.totalWriteLatency.average"} |
    Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
    Select -ExpandProperty Average
  $VMReadIOPSAverage = $_.Group |
    where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.numberReadAveraged.average"} |
    Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
    Select -ExpandProperty Average
  $VMWriteIOPSAverage = $_.Group |
    where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.numberWriteAveraged.average"} |
    Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
    Select -ExpandProperty Average
  $_.Group | Group-Object -Property Instance | %{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      VM = $vmName
      Host = $_.Group[0].Entity.Host.Name
      Datastore = $dsTab[$($_.Values[0])]
      Start = $start
      DSReadLatencyAvg = [math]::Round(($_.Group | 
          where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.totalReadLatency.average"} |
          Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
          Select -ExpandProperty Average),2)
      DSWriteLatencyAvg = [math]::Round(($_.Group | 
          where {$_.MetricId -eq "datastore.totalWriteLatency.average"} |
          Measure-Object -Property Value -Average |
          Select -ExpandProperty Average),2)
      VMReadLatencyAvg = [math]::Round($VMReadLatency,2)
      VMWriteLatencyAvg = [math]::Round($VMWriteLatency,2)
      VMReadIOPSAvg = [math]::Round($VMReadIOPSAverage,2)
      VMWriteIOPSAvg = [math]::Round($VMWriteIOPSAverage,2)
    }
  }
} | Export-Csv c:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

When I check with any datastore, I am not able to find stat **"datastore.totalReadLatency.average","datastore.totalWriteLatency.average"**

Please let me know what is wrong I am doing or is there anything which needs to be done ( any update/Installation )

Answer (score 0):

Running your

> Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat -Start $start

in PowerCLI v12.4 I see errors like below and no data returned

> The metric counter "datastore.totalreadlatency.average" doesn't exist for
> entity <$vmname>

which led me to [this thread](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/Script-to-list-vm-io-latency-and-the-datastore-the-vm-is-on/td-p/2161473) where the solution code looks close to yours. Anyway, using `-Realtime` seems to fix that piece for your last-hour scenario. Offhand I'm not sure if something changed in recent versions, or what.

Not finding this documented, but `Get-Stat` appears to ignore `-Start` when `-Realtime` is specified. So try

```
Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat -Realtime
```

(Maybe you grabbed the `$stat` definition from the first answer in that thread, but grabbed the remaining code from the accepted answer? You're attempting to parse results for `numberReadAveraged` & `numberWriteAveraged` without gathering those results.)

To look beyond realtime/last-hour, you'd need collection [level](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vcenter.configuration.doc/GUID-5D85751A-2CE8-4FD5-83C8-90A17060631E.html) 3 or higher for [totalReadLatency](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-9F7A28BA-DB06-4215-A1D4-3474404E041E.html) and [totalWriteLatency](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-F8EF57D2-0B27-4972-BE73-F985EE3B94A3.html). Increasing stat levels will grow the vCenter db.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but the data needed is for past hours and i don't think using -Realtime will solve my problem.  now my only concern is why `"datastore.totalReadLatency.average","datastore.totalWriteLatency.average"` is not visible when i do get-stattype. Is there any config/installation need to be done for this?

Comment: Have you tried -Realtime? That seemed to solve it for me.

Comment: I tried but that is which I am not looking for. we need time interval data

Comment: For me at stat level 1, `Get-StatType` does not return these counters for for datastore or vm entities. `Get-Stat` does return them for vm entities, but only with `-Realtime`. How about for you? Sounds like you may be looking for help with the summation piece. Posting an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will get you better help.

Comment: there are around 2000 servers which the script is scanning and out of which for around 250 servers the values are present. rest it is not available. that's the reason wanting to find out what is the reason it is present in some servers and not in others. any installation needed?